# how to fix " 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'posts' "

Tags: python, django

bookmark model :

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'content'
        verbose_name_plural = _('Bookmarks')
        unique_together = [['user', 'post']]
```

I want a query to return the user's bookmarked posts ,

I tried this one `Bookmark.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by('-created_at').posts()` and it return this error :

`AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'posts'`

**update:**

Bookmark.objects.filter() returns a queryset. It has no posts attribute, just like the error says.

However, you can go about it a different way. Since you want to find Post objects, query the Post model instead of Bookmark model.

Post.objects.filter(bookmarks__user=user)

See here for more details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Try instead .posts() - [0].posts() in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bookmark.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by('-created_at').posts()
```

will return a `QuerySet` which is a list. In order to access the object in that list, you can either get the first element of the returned list:

```
Bookmark.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by('-created_at')[0].posts()
```

or use `get()` (instead of `filter()`):

```
Bookmark.objects.get(user_id=user.id).order_by('-created_at').posts()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for the "post" field in Bookmark. You are getting a QuerySet, it returns a lists of objects, try to get this using a for statement

```
query = Bookmark.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by('-created_at')

for item in query:
   item.post
```

the result of the query has no attribute posts()